# How to append string in js file using ant build

Tags: javascript, ant

I want to append data to a js file at specific location using ant build

Here is the js file

```
fun1= function(){
    var data="data1";
}
```

I want to append one line only if this does not exist in file

```
data =data+"data2";
```

inside the fun1. Is there any way to do so as xmltask is specific to XML files only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this using condition

```
<condition property="pluginEntryExists">
    <resourcecontains resource="js_file_location" substring="data =data+'data2';"/>
</condition>
```

and based on property set target will be executed

```
<target name="append-data" unless="${pluginEntryExists}">
    <!-- to support propertyregex include antcontrib.jar -->
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="./lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <loadfile property="configFileData" srcFile="js_file_location" />
    <propertyregex property="pluginList" input="${configFileData}" regexp='var data=".*;' select="\0" />

    <replaceregexp file="js_file_location" match='var data=".*;' replace="${pluginList}data+='data2';" />
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a token replacement. in JS format your string as:

```
fun1= function(){
    var data="data1 @@@@";
}
```

and then in ant you can say:

```
<replace file="script.js" token="@@@@" value="data2"/>
```

and it will replace the symbols `@@@@` with the value `data2`

just be careful, the replacement is done in place, so don't perform it on your original source code but on a compiled version or, at least, a copy. Otherwise you'll be able to perform the replacement just once.

Comment: but token (say @@@) can occur at multiple places in file. thats why I am appending the js code that is data =data+"data2";

Comment: well i guess it's your job to pick the right token. it doesn't have to be a meaningless series of symbols, you can get specific and use something like `${injected.data2}` as a token. Very little chance of that being used elsewhere by mistake ...